# Hibernate e lista de objeto

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou desenvolvendo minha primeira aplicação em java, aplicação desktop com Netbeans e hibernate.

Tenho as tabelas `membros` e `estadocivil`. O membro possui um estado civil. Mapeei as classes utilizando o Hibernate e na classe Membros ele criou o atributo `EstadoCivil`. Meu select no hibernate é

```
from membros mb join mb.EstadoCivil"
```

Meu problema é que está sendo retornada uma lista de objetos, e não de membros, e não consigo recuperar os dados. Como retornar uma lista de Membros ou converter o object em Membros? Segue abaixo o código:

```
public List Select() {
    List lista = new ArrayList();
    try {
        this.sessao = Sessao.getSessao();
        transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        query = sessao.createQuery("from Membros");
        lista = query.list();
        sessao.close();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao realizar consulta!\n" + 
            e.getMessage(), null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta mudar o retorno do seu método para o tipo de objeto que você necessita, e o próprio NETBEANs vai obrigar você a fazer cast.

Vai ficar algo, mais ou menos, assim :

```
public Membro Select() {
    Membro lista = new ArrayList();
    try {
        this.sessao = Sessao.getSessao();
        transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
        query = sessao.createQuery("from Membros");
        lista = (Membro) query.list();
        sessao.close();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao realizar consulta!\n" + 
            e.getMessage(), null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return  lista;
}
```